# Navigating Event in AWS Lambda Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

So I'm fairly new to both AWS and Python. I'm on a uni assignment and have hit a road block.

I'm uploading data to AWS S3, this information is being sent to an SQS Queue and passed into AWS Lambda. I know, it would be much easier to just go straight from S3 to Lambda...but apparently "that's not the brief".

So I've got my event accurately coming into AWS Lambda, but no matter how deep I dig, I can't reach the information I need. In AMS Lambda, I run the following query.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
print(event)
```

Via CloudWatch, I get the output

```
{'Records': [{'messageId': '1d8e0a1d-d7e0-42e0-9ff7-c06610fccae0', 'receiptHandle': 'AQEBr64h6lBEzLk0Xj8RXBAexNukQhyqbzYIQDiMjJoLLtWkMYKQp5m0ENKGm3Icka+sX0HHb8gJoPmjdTRNBJryxCBsiHLa4nf8atpzfyCcKDjfB9RTpjdTZUCve7nZhpP5Fn7JLVCNeZd1vdsGIhkJojJ86kbS3B/2oBJiCR6ZfuS3dqZXURgu6gFg9Yxqb6TBrAxVTgBTA/Pr35acEZEv0Dy/vO6D6b61w2orabSnGvkzggPle0zcViR/shLbehROF5L6WZ5U+RuRd8tLLO5mLFf5U+nuGdVn3/N8b7+FWdzlmLOWsI/jFhKoN4rLiBkcuL8UoyccTMJ/QTWZvh5CB2mwBRHectqpjqT4TA3Z9+m8KNd/h/CIZet+0zDSgs5u', 'body': '{"Records":[{"eventVersion":"2.1","eventSource":"aws:s3","awsRegion":"eu-west-2","eventTime":"2021-03-26T01:03:53.611Z","eventName":"ObjectCreated:Put","userIdentity":{"principalId":"MY_ID"},"requestParameters":{"sourceIPAddress":"MY_IP_ADD"},"responseElements":{"x-amz-request-id":"BQBY06S20RYNH1XJ","x-amz-id-2":"Cdo0RvX+tqz6SZL/Xw9RiBLMCS3Rv2VOsu2kVRa7PXw9TsIcZeul6bzbAS6z4HF6+ZKf/2MwnWgzWYz+7jKe07060bxxPhsY"},"s3":{"s3SchemaVersion":"1.0","configurationId":"test","bucket":{"name":"MY_BUCKET","ownerIdentity":{"principalId":"MY_ID"},"arn":"arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET"},"object":{"key":"test.jpg","size":246895,"eTag":"c542637a515f6df01cbc7ee7f6e317be","sequencer":"00605D33019AD8E4E5"}}}]}', 'attributes': {'ApproximateReceiveCount': '1', 'SentTimestamp': '1616720643174', 'SenderId': 'AIDAIKZTX7KCMT7EP3TLW', 'ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp': '1616720648174'}, 'messageAttributes': {}, 'md5OfBody': '1ab703704eb79fbbb58497ccc3f2c555', 'eventSource': 'aws:sqs', 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:sqs:eu-west-2:ARN', 'awsRegion': 'eu-west-2'}]}
```

[Disclaimer, I've tried to edit out any identifying information but if there's any sensitive data I'm not understanding or missed, please let me know]

Anyways, just for a sample, I want to get the Object Key, which is test.jpg. I tried to drill down as much as I can, finally getting to: -

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
print(event['Records'][0]['body'])
```

This returned the following (which was nice to see fully stylized): -

```
{
"Records": [
    {
        "eventVersion": "2.1",
        "eventSource": "aws:s3",
        "awsRegion": "eu-west-2",
        "eventTime": "2021-03-26T01:08:16.823Z",
        "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
        "userIdentity": {
            "principalId": "MY_ID"
        },
        "requestParameters": {
            "sourceIPAddress": "MY_IP"
        },
        "responseElements": {
            "x-amz-request-id": "ZNKHRDY8GER4F6Q5",
            "x-amz-id-2": "i1Cazudsd+V57LViNWyDNA9K+uRbSQQwufMC6vf50zQfzPaH7EECsvw9SFM3l3LD+TsYEmnjXn1rfP9GQz5G5F7Fa0XZAkbe"
        },
        "s3": {
            "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
            "configurationId": "test",
            "bucket": {
                "name": "MY_BUCKET",
                "ownerIdentity": {
                    "principalId": "MY_ID"
                },
                "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET"
            },
            "object": {
                "key": "test.jpg",
                "size": 254276,
                "eTag": "b0052ab9ba4b9395e74082cfd51a8f09",
                "sequencer": "00605D3407594DE184"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

However, from this stage on if I try to write print(event['Records'][0]['body']['Records']) or print(event['Records'][0]['s3']), I'll get told I require an integer, not a string. If I try to write print(event['Records'][0]['body'][0]), I'll be given a single character every time (in this cause the first { bracket).

I'm not sure if this has something to do with tuples, or if at this stage it's all saved as one large string, but at least in the output view it doesn't appear to be saved that way.

Does anyone have any idea what I'd do from this stage to access the further information? In the full release after I'm done testing, I'll be wanting to save an audio file and the file name as opposed to a picture.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are having this problem because the contents of the `body` is a JSON. But in string format. You should parse it to be able to access it like a normal dictionary. Like so:

```py
import json

def handler(event: dict, context: object):
    body = event['Records'][0]['body']
    body = json.loads(body)
    # use the body as a normal dictionary
```

You are getting only a single char when using integer indexes because it is a string. So, using `[n]` in an string will return the nth char.

Comment: Awesome this worked perfect, I appreciate it mate. I'd actually tried something along the lines of body = JSON.parse(...) before but either the syntax/command is wrong, or I loaded in the incorrect elements.

Comment: And for anyone that wants to know the exact print command that I used after, in case it helps, it is print(body['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])

Answer (score 2):

It's because your getting stringified JSON data. You need to load it back to its Python dict format.

There is a useful package called lambda_decorators. you can install with `pip install lambda_decorators`

so you can do this:

```
from lambda_decorators import load_json_body

@load_json_body
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event['Records'][0]['body'])

    # Now you can access the the items in the body using there index and keys.
```

This will extract the JSON for you.